# How to insert an item into an array at a specific index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following array

```
0: {value: 29, label: "Hamgurguesas Carne"}
1: {value: 31, label: "Pizza Cancha"}
2: {value: 28, label: "Pizza Muzzarella"}
```

But i want to renumber the index equal to the value

Example:

```
29: {value: 29, label: "Hamgurguesas Carne"}
31: {value: 31, label: "Pizza Cancha"}
28: {value: 28, label: "Pizza Muzzarella"}
```

I tried with .slice but i don't have lucky, is any way to do this, before or after the array created

Comment: what would be array[0] to array[28]?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because it is easier for me to evaluate by index than by value within the asosative array

Comment: It seems you're not trying to reindex your array (which is possible). But rather to a have dictionary object with keys the same as `value`.

Comment: what if you happen to have 2 or more items with the same value?

Comment: why it is easier for you to evaluate by index than by value? it looks like you don't understand how to use array properly.. using value should not be harder than using index, you just have to know how to use it

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for :)

More info about methods used in the solution:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```js
const o = {
   0: {value: 29, label: "Hamgurguesas Carne"},
   1: {value: 31, label: "Pizza Cancha"},
   2: {value: 28, label: "Pizza Muzzarella"},
};

const res = Object.entries(o).reduce((s, [_, v]) => (s[v.value] = v, s), {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Try to explain the two functions you used Object.entries and array.reduce and the destructuring you used.

Answer (score 1):

You can't renumber the index of an array. It is a sequential number automatically set to identify the position of your information inside the array.
It always starts with 0 - the first element.

Maybe what you want is not to use an array, but an object wrapping your objects.
Like this:

```
const comidas = {
  29: {value: 29, label: "Hamgurguesas Carne"}
  31: {value: 31, label: "Pizza Cancha"}
  28: {value: 28, label: "Pizza Muzzarella"}
};
```

This way you could access your inner objects by the keys 29, 31 or 28, for example.
The only thing with this is that you have to pay attention because as your keys are always treated as strings, you can't access them using . as you normally would; but you have to use [ ]:

Bad:

```
comidas.29 >> ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError
```

Ok:

```
comidas[29] >> {value: 29, label: "Hamgurguesas Carne"}
comidas[29].label >> "Hamgurguesas Carne"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out

```
// assign new key with value of prior key
array[29] = array[0];

// remove prior key
delete array[0];
```

Comment: i think you meant `array[29]  = array[0]`

Comment: Yeah. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is definitely not good. You would generate 26 empty spaces on your array that could potentially lead to serious code bugs. You'd have an array with 4 values and a length of 30. Avoid at all costs this option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't renumber array. It is allways has index from 0 to (array length - 1).

You can, for example, add first 28 elements to your array.

Another way: you can use object instead of array.

```
var dict = {};
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    dict[arr[i]['value']] = arr[i];
}
```